# get contents of iframe on keyup

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, contenteditable, onkeyup

i've seen tons of posts on this but none work for some reason.

What I'm interested in is putting the stuff I type into a *contenteditable* `<iframe>` into a `<textarea>` and `<div>`.

here's my HTML:

```
<textarea ></textarea>
<iframe></iframe>
<div></div>
```

here's my JS:

```
var iframeBody=$('iframe').contents().find('body');
iframeBody.attr('contenteditable', true);

$(document.body).on( 'keyup', iframeBody, function() {   
  var txt = $(this).html();
  $('div').html(txt);
  $('textarea').val(txt);
});
```

​
here's the JSfiddle if you'd like to make a suggestion: http://jsfiddle.net/nyPAM/21/

any help would be greatly appreciated, this thing is driving me nuts,

thanks,
tim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var iframeBody=$('iframe').contents().find('body');
iframeBody.attr('contenteditable', true);

$(iframeBody).on( 'keyup',function() {
    var txt = $(this).html();
    $('div').html(txt);
    $('textarea').val(txt);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GtXzz/

Comment: It works for me in FF 11.0 and Chrome 18.0.1025.162 and even in IE 6

Comment: sorry stupid mistake, i was confused, the textarea was on the left, iframe on the right, keying up textarea didn't do anything, ugh!

Comment: @stewe Is there a way to do this if the iframe is in design mode instead of contenteditable?